# How to use Line Height plugin in CKEditor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, plugins, ckeditor4.x

I'm trying to use the Line Height plugin on CKEditor 4.5.3 but it won't work.

CKEditor won't even open. I get a blank space where it should be.

Could someone please help me?

Here's a link to my CKEditor build: [link](http://ckeditor.com/builder/b4a54de5fbf8bffad1def0eac216edcc)

Here's what my console says:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
```

And it points to this code line (plugin.js:70):

```
addCombo( editor, 'lineheight', 'size', editor.lang.lineheight.title, config.line_height, editor.lang.lineheight.title, config.lineHeight_style, 40 );
```

Here are some images to help clarify:

[image: error]

[image: code]

PS: Rich Combo, a required plugin for Line Height to work, is installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I went through the same problem, and it was a bug in the language I was using.

In the file:

```
ckeditor/plugins/lineheight/lang/pt.js
```

It had the content below referencing the language 'af' being that it should be 'pt'

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.setLang('lineheight','af', {
    title: 'linha Altura'
});
```

Corrected to:

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.setLang('lineheight','pt', {
    title: 'linha Altura'
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Line Height plugin apart from the Rich Combo plugin requires 4 more plugins as dependencies:

- richcombo
- floatpanel
- panel
- listblock
- button

and in your `config.js`

```
config.extraPlugins = 'lineheight,richcombo,floatpanel,panel,listblock,button';
```